# Kernel install gives missing module error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, linux-kernel

I'm installing a linux kernel from 3.14 to 3.19 and when I run the command:

```
make O=$BUILD install
```

I get the several error messages saying that there is no lib/module directory. Before this I already compiled the kernel and copied the bzImage that was created into boot, along with system.map and .config.

```
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0
    WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.19.0
    Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
    depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.19.0: No such    file or directory
    depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_6tPRIQ/lib/modules  /3.19.0/modules.order: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_6tPRIQ/lib/modules  /3.19.0/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.19.0 /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.19.0 /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.19.0 /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0
    Generating grub configuration file ...
    Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT: ls /

```
bin    dev   initrd.img  lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
boot   etc   lib         media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
cdrom  home  lib64       mnt         root  srv   usr
```

EDIT 2:

```
ls -l /lib/
total 296
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 feb 21 10:41 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 brltty
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 feb 20 13:04 cpp -> /etc/alternatives/cpp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 crda
drwxr-xr-x 61 root root 20480 feb 21 10:43 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 hdparm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 ifupdown
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 init
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 71512 dec 24  2013 klibc-P2s_k-  gf23VtrGgO2_4pGkQgwMY.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 feb 20 13:04 libip4tc.so.0 -> libip4tc.so.0.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 27392 jan  8  2014 libip4tc.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17 feb 20 13:04 libip6tc.so.0 -> libip6tc.so.0.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31520 jan  8  2014 libip6tc.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16 feb 20 13:04 libiptc.so.0 -> libiptc.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  5816 jan  8  2014 libiptc.so.0.0.0 
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    20 feb 20 13:04 libxtables.so.10 -> libxtables.so.10.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47712 jan  8  2014 libxtables.so.10.0.0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 linux-sound-base
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 jul 22  2014 lsb
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 apr 10  2014 modprobe.d
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 modules
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 modules-load.d
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 feb 21 10:41 plymouth
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 recovery-mode
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 resolvconf
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 feb 21 10:41 systemd
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096 mar 22  2014 terminfo
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 feb 21 10:45 udev
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 ufw
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 12288 feb 21 10:42 x86_64-linux-gnu
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 jul 23  2014 xtables
```

Comment: can you show `ls /` output. Do you need to be root?

Comment: I added ls / output in main post. I called the command with sudo make O=... if thats what you mean.

Comment: how about `ls -l /lib/`

Comment: Added it to the main post.

Comment: Can you try doing `make O=$BUILD modules_install" before doing `make install`. And see if `/lib/modules/3.10.0` is created?

Comment: Yes I started it, no folder created yet, but will have to wait for it to finish I guess. Might take a while, gonna update you when it's done. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If it does not help, try creating the `/lib/modules/3.19.0` directory. and then run `make install` again.

Comment: I finished the command and also ran make O=$BUILD modules and then make O=$BUILD install and then it worked. Succesfully updated to the new kernel now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK let me put as an answer for others.

Comment: It would be good to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) @Miline answer, thereby making it clear that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Try doing.

```
  make O=$BUILD modules
  make O=$BUILD modules_install
```

and then

```
  make O=$BUILD install
```